# Dolphin Emulator doesn't find disk partition, /mnt and /media are not accessible ( Ubuntu )

Tags: ubuntu

Dolphin emulator doesn't have privileges to access OTHER LOCATIONS ( external storage or any other disk partitions ), despite having

- Ownership claimed.
- Access of all parties (root, user, other) set to read and write and ACL changed accordingly

---

To be noted /mnt & /media has unmodifiable access to root(/).

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved by mounting the desired storage at

```
 /home/*your-user-name*/
```

The mounting point can be changed by the terminal or by DISK ( preinstalled app )

### *Please follow the mouse pointer in the steps below*

[[image: unmount the partition with the games needed to be accessed][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J54id.png)
[image: click the gear icon]
[image: edit mount options]
[image: turn off user session defaults]
[image: change the region before disk ID]

That should bring the disk to your home directory, and Dolphin can access that.

[image]

---

This is not a solution just a way around if anyone is able to identify the ACL problem please help the community.

Thank you